# Include the options for accessibility here will it work

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, redux

I am working on accessibility for high charts, I was looking at their example and their implementation is different from mine.

In mine I am trying to import the chart component from another module. So if I include the options for accessibility here will it work or do I need to add in sports-chart project?

My code is below:

```
import React, {Component, PropTypes} from 'react';
import SportsGraph from 'sports-kick';
import SportsGraphMore from 'sports-kick/sports-kick-more';
import SportsGraphNoData from 'sports-kick/modules/no-data-to-display';
import SportsGraphAccessibility from 'sports-kick/modules/accessibility';

import './css/chart.css';

debugger;

export class Sports extends Component {
    static mergeVariousValues(chartVariousValues) {
        const lang = chartVariousValues.lang;
        debugger;

        return {
            ...chartVariousValues,
            lang: {
                ...lang,
                noData: (lang && lang.noData) || 'There is no data to show here yet.'
            }
        };
    }

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.refSports = this.refSports.bind(this);
        this.mergeConfigs = this.mergeConfigs.bind(this);
        this.renderSports = this.renderSports.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.renderSports(this.props);
    }

    shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps) {
        if (!nextProps.shouldUpdate || nextProps.playersOptions === this.props.playersOptions) {
            return true;
        }

        this.renderSports(nextProps);
        return false;
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        (this.chart && this.chart.destroy());
    }

    mergeConfigs(chartConfig) {
        const chart = chartConfig.chart;

        return {
            ...chartConfig,
            chart: {
                ...chart,
                renderTo: this.chart
            },
            credits: {
                enabled: false
            },
            noData: {
                useHTML: true
            },
            accessibility: {
                keyboardNavigation: {
                    skipNullPoints: true
                }
            }
        };
    }

    renderSports(props) {
        debugger;
        SportsGraphNoData(SportsGraph);
        SportsGraphAccessibility(SportsGraph);

        const {playersOptions, options, withMore} = props;

        (withMore && SportsGraphMore(SportsGraph));

        (options && SportsGraph.setVariousValues(Sports.mergeVariousValues(options)));

        this.chart = SportsGraph['chart'](this.mergeConfigs(playersOptions));

        const view = typeof global === 'undefined' ? window : global;
        view.requestAnimationFrame && requestAnimationFrame(() => {
            (this.chart && this.chart.redraw() && this.chart.reflow());
        });
    }

    refSports(chart) {
        this.chart = chart;
    }

    render() {
        debugger;
        console.log("simulation-tool");

        return (<div ref={this.refSports} />);
    }
}

Sports.propTypes = {
    playersOptions: PropTypes.shape({
        chart: PropTypes.object.isRequired
    }).isRequired,
    options: PropTypes.object,
    shouldUpdate: PropTypes.bool,
    withMore: PropTypes.bool
};

Sports.defaultProps = {
    shouldUpdate: true,
    withMore: false
};

export default Sports;
```

I am planning to include code from [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0s3tyf5c/) in this file.

Or do I need to include [another project](https://jsfiddle.net/96z65fbr/) file?

Comment: actual demo 
http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/3.1.1/highcharts/highch

Comment: @all : can yu help me

Comment: This question is really unclear. Where is your code relating to accessibility? Also, post relevant code here, not just in external links which may not last forever and will make the question less valuable to future visitors looking for similar answers.

Comment: @Jacob thanks for your reply...I updated my code in question as well as here  https://jsfiddle.net/yks64h8u/